# Can anyone solve this continuity problem?

Tags: continuity

Let the function $f(x)$ be defined as:
 $$
f(x) =
 \begin{cases}
    \sin {\frac {1}{x}},& \text{if } x \neq 0 \\ 
      0 ,              & \text{if }  x= 0
\end{cases}
$$

Is this function continuous at $ x=0$ ?

Comment: In every neighborhood of $0$ $\sin\frac1x$ is both positive and negative, so $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: Actually, the condition of being positive and negative in every neighborhood of $0$ does not preclude continuity at $0$.  (However, in this case, I agree that the function is not continuous at $0$).

Answer (score 1):

No. If you let $x_n=\frac1{n\pi}$ for each $n\ge1$, then $f(x_n)=0$, but if you let $y_n=\frac2{(2n+1)\pi}$ then $f(y_n)=1$. Since both $x_n,y_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, $f(x)$ does not approach a single limit as $x\to0$. In particular it is not continuous at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Consider the sequences
$$
x_n=\frac{1}{2n\pi+\pi/2}\quad\text{and}\quad y_n=\frac{1}{2n\pi-\pi/2}.
$$
Then
$$
x_n,y_n\to 0,
$$
but
$$
f(x_n)=1\quad\text{while}\quad f(y_n)=-1.
$$